# Can we get the object name using "this" pointer

Tags: c++

I want to know, is there any possibility that we can get current object name using "this" pointer in C++.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Other than the ambiguity that OP means object `variable name` or object `type` there is nothing wrong in the Q.So please understand the OP is a new user and allow him/her to clarify that bit.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean:

```
Myclass obj;
```

then you want to know the name of the object is `obj` and you want to do this through `this`

Answer is:
No You cannot. There is no reflection available in C++.

Comment: There is a very small amount of reflection available.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I believe not in a standardized way but It would be nice to know more about that,Can you provide some references?

Comment: @Als: `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` are rudimentary reflection features.

Comment: He's probably talking about RTTI. The non-standardized bit is the actual strings returned by type_info::name(), but comparing type_infos should be portable. I.e. iff two objects have the same type their type_infos should compare as equal.

Comment: Ofcourse RTTI can be called as reflection as well,Silly me,I was expecting some neat hackery other than RTTI.

Comment: Reflection in C++ is limited to types, anyway, not individual objects. Considering the question expicitly mentions `this`, I'd say the OP is aware of the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume there were a function `getName()` that returned the "name" of the object.  What do you expect the result to be for the following code?

```
struct Object {
  Object() { getName(); }
  void getName() { cout << getName(this) << endl; }
};

int main() {
  new Object;
}
```

Or how about this one?

```
int main() {
   Object o;
   Object& r = o;
   r.getName(); //should it print `r` or `o`?
}
```

In short: no, of course not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
struct C
{
    C(){
        std::cout<<typeid(*this).name()<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    C c;
}
```

Comment: This gives the `type` not the `name`.

Comment: Als's and mine answers are completely different. If I missed the point, please let me know